# Is there a mathematical way to maximise the values to the solution of a simultaneous equation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

So I am trying to write a computer program to calculate quantities for Chicken feed based on the % of protein in the feed

Here is a snippet with the example of how it works

```
Assuming that the farmer wants to make feed with a 19% DCP [Digestible Crude Protein] 
The farmer may use: 

 - Whole maize (8.23 %DCP) 
 - Soya (45 % DCP) 
 - Omena (55 % DCP) 
 - Maize bran (7 % DCP) 



To make a 70 kg bag of feed for layers, a farmer would require the following ingredients:
    
    34 kg of whole maize
    12 kg of Soya
    8 kg of omena
    10 kg of maize bran


To get the weight of crude protein:

 A) Whole maize = 34 kg x 8.23 ÷100 = 2.80kg
 B) Soya bean = 12 kg x 45 ÷ 100 = 5.40 kg
 C) Omena = 8 kg x 55 ÷ 100 = 4.40 kg
 D) Maize bran = 10 kg x 7 ÷ 100 = 0.70 kg

(Total crude protein 13.30 kg)
```

Finally to get the total crude protein content of all these ingredients in a 70 kg bag, you take the total crude protein content of the combined ingredients, divide by 70 and multiply by 100 thus,

```
(13.30 ÷ 70) x 100 = 19.0 %.
```

Now there are infinite combinations of these 4 ingridents that would give a 19% crude protein. The general equations being

$ \frac{A*0.082 + B*0.45 + C*0.55 + D*0.07}{A+B+C+D} = 0.19$

Intuitively I think there could be a single solution to find a situation where values of A,B,C and D are as high as possible. So a solution where we use as much of each ingredient as possible by weight.

This is where I am not stuck as in the approach. What I thought of trying is starting all values with an arbitrary weight say 50kg. Then for each value of A,B,C and D adjust
only one value to get how much to adjust each one to get to a solution for that single ingredient. for example for A

$ A = \frac{0.19(B + C + D)-(B*0.45 + C*0.55 + D*0.07)}{0.082-0.19}$

Then i substitute values of BCD with 50 to get the new weight of A then get the % increase or decrease of A vs it's previous value (of 50)

I repeat this for all values and see what the + increases or decreases were. so for example i could get

A  -5%
B  +20%
C  +10%
D  -2%

I then 'normalise this by dividing by the smallest % increase. then finally use the final answers the increases/decreases i need to apply to those A,B,C and D values

This is an intuitive approach which could be wrong, I was wondering if there is a mathematical way to do this. Any help will be really appreciated by myself and my chickens

```
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠲⠾⢶⣦⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣶⣾⣿⣹⣇⡶⠆
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⡇⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣤⡴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡗⡁⠀⠀
⢀⣾⣿⠷⣶⣄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣀⣴⣿⣿⣷⣽⣿⣿⣿⣿⣟⣠⣧⠀⠀
⢣⣀⣿⣿⣾⣝⢷⣄⠀⠀⢀⣤⣶⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣞⡻⡿⣿⣿⣿⠀⠀
⠘⢖⣈⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠋⣱⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣷⣵⡽⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠉⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢖⣴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢿⣿⣿⣿⠇⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢻⣿⣿⣿⣿⢿⣷⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢃⣼⣿⣿⡟⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠹⣿⣯⣵⣿⠿⠋⠿⠿⠿⠿⣿⣟⣛⣭⣵⣿⣿⣿⠏⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠛⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠛⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠛⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠙⠛⣿⠋⠁⠉⢳⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢧⠀⠀⠔⠻⠿⡶⠤⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⣷⣤⠤⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⠏⠓⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
```

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler_diet

Comment: thank you @RobPratt linear programming is what i am after